# setCustomValidity to Bootstrap 4 validaiton?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, bootstrap-4

I have this html to display a error message

```html
<form id="order-form" class="needs-validation" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
<div id="quantity-zero" class="invalid-feedback"></div>
```

I get Bootstrap validation on all fields but I also whant to add this to my validaiton.

```
$("#previewBtn").click(function(event) {
    var form = $("#order-form");
    var quantitySelected = null;

    $(".quantity-select").each(function () {
        if($(this).val() > 0) {
            quantitySelected = true;
            return false;
        } else {
            quantitySelected = false;
            //$("#quantity-zero").show();
        }
    })
```

If quantitySelected is false I want to add this to by bootstrap error, below gives the error.

> Error: TypeError: $(...).form is undefined

```
if(quantitySelected === false) {
    $("#quantity-zero").form.setCustomValidity('This is an error.');
    }
```

I validate the form with this

```
    if (form[0].checkValidity() === false) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        } else {
        $("#exampleModal").show();
    }
    form.addClass('was-validated');
    
});
```

How can I display an error together with my other bootrap validation if `quantitySelected` is false?

Comment: `return` in `each` method? what is `$("#quantity-zero").form`? I guess it should be `$("#quantity-zero").setCustomValidity('This is an error.');`

Comment: form the the object I use in the validation. var form = $(....

Comment: Then you can directly use `form.setCustomValidity()`.

Comment: And this is what I'am doing but you see my error.

Comment: You are using `$("#quantity-zero").form.setCustomValidity()`, instead try using `form.setCustomValidity()`.